# UV's not on top of texture in UV Editor - How to repeat texture?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I would like to change a UV map of a model. The problem is that only the texture of the head is on top of the texture. Is there a way to repeat the texture so that I can work on other parts as well?

[image]

Comment: Set Mapping to **repeat**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just go to: *Sidebar > View > Repeat Image*

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried to find such an option several times, but I was never able to find it.

Comment: wow didn't even know this option, thanks

Comment: @moonboots It's weirdly satisfying to know something about Blender you didn't :). Made my day.

Comment: well I think you over estimate me a lot, so many things I don't know  :((  but yes this one was basic